# Letting Browser control Scrolling CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am using dynatree to create an accordian view. When I exapand the accordian i want it to exapand to accomadate space for as much text as is provided. Then you the scrollbar on the browser if the text runs further than the screen. I dont want scroll bars in the space where the text is (overflow:hidden). how can I expand so it will display correctly?

[image]

Here is the class on "section with the text in it"

```
#expanderHtml{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;

    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
    -mox-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff;
    behavior: url(../Css/PIEFiles/PIE.htc);

}
```

Here is the class on the gray box behind the the box with the text..

```
.ViewWrapper{
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    position: relative;
    -mox-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 243px;
}
```

I need the dynatree to expand as far as the text goes down, if its too far then you can scroll the rest of the way

Comment: Right now it's not immediately clear what you're asking for.  Can you provide some code and describe what's going wrong with it?

Comment: Your section with text in it has overlapped from it's container. Am I right?

Comment: yes..also the text is too and I cant use the browser scroll to get to the bottom currentl

Comment: It usually happens when you have a floated element inside your wrapper, but I can't see any float rule in the code you have provided.

Comment: I would suggest you to put a `clearfix` before closing your wrapper tag.